# Canceling an UIView Animation Block

Tags: objective-c, block, uiviewanimation

The code below shows an animation of a label which contains a status message for the user. If an event happens the label is showing prompt and is slowly disappearing via uiview animation block.

```
- (void)showStatusOnLabelWithString:(NSString *)statusMessage
{   
    // [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; // not working
    [labelStatus.layer removeAllAnimations]; // not working, too

    [labelStatus setText:statusMessage];
    [labelStatus setHidden:NO];
    [labelStatus setAlpha:1.0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^
     {
         [labelStatus setAlpha:0.0];

     } completion:^(BOOL finished) 
     {
         [labelStatus setHidden:YES];
         [labelStatus setAlpha:1.0];
     }];
}
```

If there is another event in the following 5s after the first the label should animate again, so I removed the previous animation with `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]` (thats what I thought). 
But the label just completely disappear and the next 5s the label is invisible again.

If I (or the user) wait(s) the 5s everything is working properly.

Why isn't this working?

Kind Regards, 
$h@rky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) 
 {
     [labelStatus setHidden:YES];
     [labelStatus setAlpha:1.0];
 }];
```

to this:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) 
 {
     if (finished) {
         [labelStatus setHidden:YES];
         [labelStatus setAlpha:1.0];
     }
 }];
```

The reason is you are reaching this completion block when you remove the animations for the layer, but `finished` will be `false` because you interrupted it. Also, the order is important here. Perhaps you were expecting `removeAllAnimations` to call the completion block instantly, but instead it will be called after your `showStatusOnLabelWithString:` method finishes, so what is happening is you are calling `setHidden:NO` followed immediately by `setHidden:YES`.

Comment: Great that works. Learned something new about the finished variable^^

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing animations from the label's layer (`labelStatus.layer`)?

Comment: Yes I did but same result -.- I updated my question adding your answer.